# How to block access to a sub-site with mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url

Let's say I have the sites `siteA.com` and `siteB.com`. They are hosted such that `siteB.com` actually points to `siteA.com/siteB`.

How can I block someone from visiting `siteA.com/siteB` using `mod_rewrite`?

So far I've tried this to no avail (in root of `siteA.com`):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/siteB/$ http://someothersite.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
# you may need to drop the leading slash if you're doing this in .htaccess   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^siteB\.com$
RewriteRule ^/siteB  http://siteB.com/ [R=301]
```